# Forbid the word administrator as username

Tags: php

I was make a function for a signup account page so someone will not can be signup with username admin or administrator. The code is below:

```php
function forbidden($word){
$forbidden = array('Admin', 'admin', 'Administrator', 'administrator', 'admin1', 'Admin1', 'admin123', 'Admin123', 'admin123456', 'Admin123456', 'Administrator1', 'Administrator2', 
'Administrator3', 'admin3', 'admin4', 'Administrator123', 'administrator123', 'administrator1', 'administrator2', 'administrator123', 'administrator3', 'aDmin', 'adMin', 'ADMIN', 
'ADMINISTRATOR', 'admIn', 'admiN', 'ADmin', 'AdMiN', 'ADmin', 'ADMin', 'ADMIn', 'aDMin', 'ADministrator', 'aDministrator', 'adMinistrator','ADMinistrator', 'ADMInistrator', 'ADMINistrator', 
'ADMINistrator', 'ADMINIstrator', 'ADMINIStrator', 'ADMINISTrator','ADMINISTRator','ADMINISTRAtor','ADMINISTRATor','ADMINISTRATOr','ADMINISTRATOR_a','ADMINISTRATOR_b');

for($i=0; $i<=count($forbidden); $i++) {
        if(isset($forbidden[$i])){
            if( $word == $forbidden[$i] ){
            $check_forbitten = "true";
            return $check_forbitten;
            break;
            }
        }

}

}
```

My question is there a more accurate and quick way to do this?

Comment: I'd probably use a case-insensitive regular expression check to see if the username begins with "admin". **Edit** Or actually just check if a lowercase substring of the first 5 characters matches "admin".

Comment: Sounds like a good opportunity to learn about the benefits of using regular expressions for pattern matching...

Comment: I really don't understand why i get downvoted again....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
function forbidden($word) {
  return !preg_match('/admin/i', $word);
}
```

Includes all your defined words and some more I suppose you want filtered out.

Maybe some fine-tuning since it look like you only want to forbid admin as the start:

```
function forbidden($word) {
  return !preg_match('/^admin/i', $word);
}
```

Beware, that this is returning the boolean true/false. If you really want a string as in your example this would work:

```
function forbidden($word) {
  return (preg_match('/^admin/i', $word) ? 'false' : 'true');
}
```

Comment: I was about to comment on `/^admin/i`

Comment: thank's best solution so far ! I will accepted as correct answer!

Answer (score 3):

the function `in_array()` would be the best to use here if you want to keep your array of forbidden words. Beside that, I would suggest something like @rickdenhaan answer and use a regex. You could use `(\d)?(admin)(istrator)?(\d)?`

```
function forbidden($word){
    $forbidden = array('Admin', 'admin', 'Administrator', 'administrator', 
        'admin1', 'Admin1', 'admin123', 'Admin123', 'admin123456', 'Admin123456', 
        'Administrator1', 'Administrator2', 
        'Administrator3', 'admin3', 'admin4', 'Administrator123', 
        'administrator123', 'administrator1', 'administrator2', 'administrator123', 
        'administrator3', 'aDmin', 'adMin', 'ADMIN', 
        'ADMINISTRATOR', 'admIn', 'admiN', 'ADmin', 'AdMiN', 'ADmin', 'ADMin', 
        'ADMIn', 'aDMin', 'ADministrator', 'aDministrator', 
        'adMinistrator','ADMinistrator', 'ADMInistrator', 'ADMINistrator', 
        'ADMINistrator', 'ADMINIstrator', 'ADMINIStrator', 
        'ADMINISTrator','ADMINISTRator','ADMINISTRAtor',
        'ADMINISTRATor','ADMINISTRATOr',
        'ADMINISTRATOR_a','ADMINISTRATOR_b');
    // word is forbidden
    return in_array($word, $forbidden));
}
```